# OpenCV Rectangle Height and Width Keep Interchanging

Tags: c++, opencv, beagleboard

I am using OpenCV on a beaglebone to track vertical and horizontal rectangles.

In order to determine whether the rectangle is horizontal or vertical I use the height width ratio extracted from a minAreaRect.

However I have noticed that sometimes, if I let the program run on a loop over the same image, the values for width and height for the same stationary rectangle swap, where it reports the previous width value as its current height and similarly for the previous height value.

This renders the code unsatisfactory because it can no longer use height/width ratio successfully.

Can someone please explain what could cause the height/width of a rectangle to swap on its own?

Here is a sample output, notice the height and width between iterations

```
Hierarchy: 1
Contour Size: 53
Contour: 0
    X: 350
    Y: 196
    Height: 236
    Width: 26
    Ratio (W/H): 0.110169
    Ratio (H/W): 9.07692
    Vert: 0
    Horiz: 0
Image proc. time: 1.9ms
Contours: 1
Hierarchy: 1
Contour Size: 83
Contour: 0
    X: 244
    Y: 300
    Height: 26
    Width: 236
    Ratio (W/H): 9.07692
    Ratio (H/W): 0.110169
    Vert: 0
    Horiz: 0
Image proc. time: 2.2ms
Contours: 1
Hierarchy: 1
Contour Size: 59
Contour: 0
    X: 350
    Y: 196
    Height: 236
    Width: 26
    Ratio (W/H): 0.110169
    Ratio (H/W): 9.07692
    Vert: 0
    Horiz: 0
Image proc. time: 2.4ms
```

And here is the code that I use to generate this output

```
vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
Target targets;


/// Show in a window
namedWindow( "Contours", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );


//Find rectangles
findContours(thresholded, contours, hierarchy, RETR_EXTERNAL, CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);

cout<<"Contours: "<<contours.size()<<endl;
cout<<"Hierarchy: "<<hierarchy.size()<<endl;


//run through all contours and remove small contours
unsigned int contourMin = 25;
for (vector<vector<Point> >::iterator it = contours.begin(); it!=contours.end(); )
{
    cout<<"Contour Size: "<<it->size()<<endl;
    if (it->size()<contourMin)
        it=contours.erase(it);
    else
        ++it;
}

//Vector for Min Area Boxes
vector<RotatedRect> minRect(contours.size());

/// Draw contours
Mat drawing = Mat::zeros(original.size(), CV_8UC3 );

NullTargets(targets);

//run through large contours to see if they are our targerts
if(!contours.empty() && !hierarchy.empty())
{



    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
    {
        //capture corners of copntour
        minRect[i] = minAreaRect(Mat(contours[i]));

        //if(hierarchy[i][100] != -1)
        drawContours( drawing, contours, i, RED, 2, 8, hierarchy, 0, Point());



        //draw a minimum box around the target in green
        Point2f rect_points[4];
        minRect[i].points(rect_points);
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        line(drawing,rect_points[j],rect_points[(j+1)%4],GREEN,1,8);

        //define minAreaBox
        Rect box;
        box.x = minRect[i].center.x - (minRect[i].size.width/2);
        box.y = minRect[i].center.y - (minRect[i].size.height/2);
        box.width = minRect[i].size.width;
        box.height = minRect[i].size.height;


        double WHRatio = box.width/((double)box.height);
        double HWRatio = ((double)box.height)/box.width;

        //check if contour is vert, we use HWRatio because it is greater that 0 for vert target
        if ((HWRatio > MinVRatio) && (HWRatio < MaxVRatio))
        {
            targets.VertGoal = true;
            targets.VerticalTarget = box;
            targets.VerticalAngle = minRect[i].angle;
            targets.VerticalCenter = Point(box.x + box.width/2, box.y + box.height/2);
            targets.Vertical_H_W_Ratio = HWRatio;
            targets.Vertical_W_H_Ratio = WHRatio;

        }
        //check if contour is horiz, we use WHRatio because it is greater that 0 for vert target
        else if ((WHRatio > MinHRatio) && (WHRatio < MaxHRatio))
        {
            targets.HorizGoal = true;
            targets.HorizontalTarget = box;
            targets.HorizontalAngle = minRect[i].angle;
            targets.HorizontalCenter = Point(box.x + box.width/2, box.y + box.height/2);
            targets.Horizontal_H_W_Ratio = HWRatio;
            targets.Horizontal_W_H_Ratio = WHRatio;
        }

        if(targets.HorizGoal && targets.VertGoal)
            targets.HotGoal = true;

        cout<<"Contour: "<<i<<endl;
        cout<<"\tX: "<<box.x<<endl;
        cout<<"\tY: "<<box.y<<endl;
        cout<<"\tHeight: "<<box.height<<endl;
        cout<<"\tWidth: "<<box.width<<endl;
        cout<<"\tangle: "<<minRect[i].angle<<endl;
        cout<<"\tRatio (W/H): "<<WHRatio<<endl;
        cout<<"\tRatio (H/W): "<<HWRatio<<endl;
        cout<<"\tVert: "<<targets.VertGoal<<endl;
        cout<<"\tHoriz: "<<targets.HorizGoal<<endl;
        cout<<"\tHot Goal: "<<targets.HotGoal<<endl;
        //rectangle(drawing,box,YELLOW);


        //ID the center in yellow
        Point center(box.x + box.width/2, box.y + box.height/2);
        line(drawing, center, center, YELLOW, 3);
        line(drawing ,Point(320,240),Point(320,240),YELLOW,3);

    }
```

Answer (score 4):

When you are working with RotatedRect you should remember that it doesn't have real width or height because they can be swapped if you add 90 degrees to angle. As a result using 'width' or 'height' of RotatedRect to initialize 'box' is problematic to say the least. If you want to compute the ratio from RotatedRect you should take angle into account. Or if you don't want to  use angle use Rect instead of RotatedRect from the beginning (replace minAreaRect with boundingRect).

On the side note, you are not filtering polygons by number vertices on them, which is usually highly unreliable number. Large polygons may have very few vertices and small ones may have a lot. You better use area of contour (from contourArea function) or area of its bounding box since you calculate it anyway.